# Multiple inotify events in one script

Tags: linux, directory, scripting, move, inotify

I'm trying to write a bash script (which is installed as a service) to watch multiple directories and move any files that are created in that directory to another directory. For example, I want to move any files created in /home/test/directory1 to /opt/directory1 but I also want to move any files created in /home/test/directory2 to /opt/directory2 but all in one script as a running service. This is my script so far;

```
#/bin/bash

directory=/home/test/directory1
archive=/home/test/archive
target=/opt/directory1

inotifywait -m "$directory" --format '%w%f' -e create |
    while read file; do
        cp "$file" "$archive"
        mv "$file" "$target"
    done
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: There is no question here. What is working as expected? What is not working as expected? What happens when you execute the script? Any error messages? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: So when the script is executed it works as intended but I want to add the same code structure into the same script but watching a different directory and move the file to a different directory as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that can be done, with a little bit of extra logic; caveat:  this assumes that any of the target directories exist in both `/home/test` and under `/opt` and that their names match.

```
#!/bin/bash
# we use an array to store the watched directories
directories=(/home/test/directory5 /home/test/directory6)
archive="/home/test/archive"
target="/opt"
inotifywait -m --format '%w%f' -r -e create "${directories[@]/#/}" | 
    while read spotted; 
        do
            cp "${spotted}" "$archive"
            mv "${spotted}" "$( echo ${spotted}|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print "/opt",$(NF-1),$NF }')"
        done
```

Another observation: should a file of the same name be created in either of your directories the target in archive will be overwritten.  You may want to think about that.

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow and I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: So it did work as desired?  Thanks for coming back on this ;)

Comment: I used this as a baseline to edit what I needed. Thanks!